Python socket and internet connection problem
In short, I recently decided to try transferring files using Python and came across the socket library. I tried to transfer files over the local network and everything worked, but as soon as I tried to connect from another network I got an error:
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] The connection was not established because...
the destination computer rejected the connection request
server
import socket
server= socket.socket (socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("0.0.0.0", 5000))
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
server.listen(2)
while True:
   client,addr=server.accept()
   client.send('Hello Client'.encode())
   print(client.recv(1024).decode())

client
import socket
client= socket.socket (socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("My public IP", 5000))
print(client.recv(1024).decode())
client.send('Hello Server!'.encode())

I tried for a long time to find a solution on the internet and found only advice to open ports and disable the firewall, but even that didn’t help (or maybe I’m stupid)
I also tried using the telnet command to check if it would connect, but in the end it didn’t work
telnet "My IP" 5000
Connecting to “My IP”...Failed to open a connection to this node on port 5000: Connection failed


Are you on a home network? Usually, home networks are set up to use a NAT, so your modem will have an external IP address, and all devices connected to the modem will be assigned private IP addresses (usually in 192.168..). If this is the case, you will likely need to set up a port forwarding rule on your modem to forward traffic incoming on port 5000 to your PC's address on the private network. You can find your private IP address using cmd+ipconfig or sometimes the modem's GUI will display connected devices.

Another option you have is to set up an SSH tunnel from the external PC to your local system. I am most familiar with doing this on linux-based systems, but it might also be possible on windows with some extra effort.
